# How do we apply JML (openJML) to Java Code?

Tags: java, netbeans, contracts, jml

How do we apply JML to Java Code? I'm still new in Design by Contracts and quite lost on how to apply it into the program.

http://jmlspecs.sourceforge.net/

**Using:**

- OpenJML
- Netbeans 7.3
- Java SDK 1.7

I have already added the OpenJML jar files into the classpath of Netbeans. i tried the cofoga google jml version where you simply 
import com.google.java.contract.Ensures;
import com.google.java.contract.Requires
then you can add the pre and post conditions

How do we specify the pre condition and post condition using openJML in my program?

Answer (score 1):

I found what that is needed; is importing the library with annotations:

```
import org.jmlspecs.annotation.Requires;
import org.jmlspecs.annotation.Ensures;
```